# Linking Multiple Implementation Files in C on Emacs

Tags: emacsclient, c++, compilation, c

I need help with linking multiple c source code files on emacs. Could anyone show me the way on how to work this out? Thanks!

Comment: In C developement: c-source files are compiled to object files `*.o`. These object files are then linked together, sometimes also involving static or dynamic librarys, to create a binary (or library). What do you mean by "linking multiple c source code files"?

Comment: By linking multiple c source code, what I meant was compiling and running source files together. And also I need to read a binary raw data file (ht3) with C. How could I achieve this? (I'm new at programming)

Comment: As far as I understand you, you should search for "how to compile C code with gcc". If you are using the gcc compiler, then it is something like `gcc -o foo *.c` on the command line. You do not necessarily need emacs for this. Maybe this helps: http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_9.html Reading the `ht3` data file is a complete different story.

Answer (score 2):

Emacs has a builtin tetris game, a psychoanalyst, and a bunch of other fun stuff, but AFAIK it does not have a linker (nor a C compiler), so I think you're either looking at the wrong place, or asking the wrong question.

The way I compile&link C files from Emacs is by writing an appropriate `Makefile` and then with <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd> which I have bound to `compile` which by default runs `make`.